# Calculating the interest rate for an annuity (Exam FM)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, actuarial-science

I have been searching for a way to solve for the interest rate given the monthly payments of a loan.  I would like to set up a problem as the following.

> $X$=monthly payment , $i$=effective interest rate for each month, $n$=the total number of payments to pay off the loan. Assume that one borrows $1$ as a loan.

I understand that the following is true

$$Xa_{\overline{n}\rceil i}=1$$

or in other words,

$$\frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i}=\frac{1}{X}$$

Here, solving for one variable given the other two seems like an easy problem, but to me that is the case only for solving for $n$ and $X$.

I tried to search for a way to solve for $i$, and I was wondering how these types of problems are solved in the exam FM.  I understand that a graphing calculator is not allowed, I am thinking that there must be a way to solve this by hand.

Can I have some input?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no direct method to solve for i. However, you can derive the formula by using newton method.See http://oakroadsystems.com/math/loan.htm#LoanInterest

Comment: Simplifying, we have $(X-i)(1+i)^{n}-X=0$. The problem involves finding the roots of a polynomial of degree $n+1$.

Comment: I see, thanks you two.  I was thinking the same thing, as "how can we solve for such a high degree polynomial? Is this a special case where we can solve it easily?"  It turns out that if a problem like this shows up on the exam it will artificially be solvable, like the polynomial ending up being a quadratic, or a solvable cubic.