# Discount rate of an annuity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

The formula for the present value of an annuity is:

$$p = \frac{a[1-(1+r)^{-n}]}{r}$$

Where:
p = present value
r = discount rate
n = number of payments

I would like to find the discount rate, since I already know the number and amount of payments, which is \$3000 $\times$ 120. Unfortunately, I have run into a bit of a situation involving a polynomial. According to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986305/calculating-the-interest-rate-for-an-annuity-exam-fm) it is not possible to isolate $r$ on one side of the equation. I am trying to avoid using goal seek in Excel. Is it possible to plug in the other values first, and then solve for $r$?

Comment: take a look at this method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method. It converges quickly in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a solution in form of infinite nested radicals.
If you put:
$(1+r)=x $ and $a/p=M$ your equation become
$$
(M+1-x)x^n=M
$$
and you find:
$$
x=\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{M}{M+1-x}}
$$
and substituting $x$ recursively you find:
$$
x=\sqrt[ n]{\dfrac{M}{M+1-\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{M}{M+1-\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{M}{M+1-\cdots     }}     }}     }}
$$
But I fear that this formula converges too slowly for an efficient computation.

Comment: You are using different variables. Is your M my p?

Comment: Sorry... my typo. I've edit $M=a/p$